# Channel not found on slack bot under Arduino, but not Bash

Tags: c++, http, arduino, slack, slack-api

I am trying to use an Arduino to post messages on Slack, but it always returns `"channel_not_found"` error.
I have tried to use to define the channel in different formats:

```
    client.println("POST " PATH " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Content-type: application/json");
    client.println("Authorization: Bearer " TOKEN);
    client.println("Host: " SERVER);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();  // Separate header from content. Important!
    client.println("{\"channel\":\"C01750LNGAU\", \"text\":\":tada:\"}");
    //OR: client.println("{\"channel\":\"#project-coffee\", \"text\":\":tada:\"}");
    //OR: client.println("{\"channel\":C01750LNGAU, \"text\":\":tada:\"}");
```

Also using the URL encoding content type:

```
    client.println("POST " PATH " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println("Authorization: Bearer " TOKEN);
    client.println("Host: " SERVER);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.println("channel=C01750LNGAU&text=:tada:");
    //OR client.println("channel=project-coffee&text=:tada:");
    //OR client.println("channel=#project-coffee&text=:tada:");
    //OR client.println("channel=\\#project-coffee&text=:tada:");
```

For comparison, using Bash with the same parameters, it works:
`curl -F token=xoxb-12... -F channel=project-coffee -F text="Blabla" https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage`, so the permissions of the bot are correct.
I suspect I am doing something subtlety stupid, but I cannot see what.

The channel is public, and the bot has permissions.

For reference, [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) is the documentation of postMessage and [here](https://api.slack.com/web#posting_json) is an example.

The full code is included here:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include "arduino_secrets.h"


char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID; 
const char password[] = SECRET_PASS;
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

// POST parameters
// curl -F token=xoxb-12... -F channel=project-coffee -F text="Blabla" https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

const char* serverName = "slack.com/api/chat.postMessage";
const char* post_channel="project-coffee";
const int port = 443;


#define SERVER "slack.com"
#define PATH   "/api/chat.postMessage"

WiFiSSLClient client;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.flush();

    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data:
  Serial.println("You are connected to the network");
  Serial.flush();

  if (client.connect(SERVER, 443)) {
    Serial.println("connected to Slack");

    client.println("POST " PATH " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Content-type: application/json");
    //client.println("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println("Authorization: Bearer " TOKEN);
    client.println("Host: " SERVER);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();  // Separate header from content. Important!
    //client.println("{\"channel\": \"#project-coffee\", \"text\": \":tada:\"}");
    client.println("{\"channel\": \"C01750LNGAU\", \"text\": \":tada:\"}");
    //client.println("{\"channel\": C01750LNGAU, \"text\": \":tada:\"}");
    //client.println("channel=C01750LNGAU&text=:tada:");
    //client.println("channel=project-coffee&text=:tada:");
    //client.println("channel=#project-coffee&text=:tada:");
    //client.println("channel=\\#project-coffee&text=:tada:");
    Serial.println();

  }
}


uint32_t bytes = 0;
void loop() {

  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
    bytes++;
  }
  if (!client.connected()) {
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("disconnecting from server.");
  client.stop();
  Serial.print("Read "); Serial.print(bytes); Serial.println(" bytes");

  // do nothing forevermore:
  while (true);
  }
}
```

The full response is:

```
date: Sun, 06 Sep 2020 13:46:30 GMT
server: Apache
x-slack-req-id: ****
x-oauth-scopes: chat:write,channels:read,groups:read,mpim:read,im:read
x-accepted-oauth-scopes: chat:write
access-control-expose-headers: x-slack-req-id, retry-after
x-slack-backend: r
x-content-type-options: nosniff
expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
x-xss-protection: 0
vary: Accept-Encoding
pragma: no-cache
access-control-allow-headers: slack-route, x-slack-version-ts, x-b3-traceid, x-b3-spanid, x-b3-parentspanid, x-b3-sampled, x-b3-flags
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
referrer-policy: no-referrer
access-control-allow-origin: *
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-via: haproxy-www-3rug,haproxy-edge-fra-eynl

{"ok":false,"error":"channel_not_found"}
```

Comment: Your bash script is passing the token in a completely different way. It's not sending the same request.

Comment: @user253751 if the token is wrong, the answer is `"channel_not_found"`, so the authentication seems correct. And the documentation says that is how it should be passed: https://api.slack.com/web#posting_json

Comment: "If the token is wrong, the answer is "channel_not_found"" -- but the answer ***is*** "channel_not_found" so are you saying the token ***is*** wrong?

Comment: @user253751 sorry, wrong paste. `invalid_auth`

Comment: What's the full request that your client sends, and what's the full request that curl sends? I bet that if you have both of these, the answer will be obvious.

Comment: @user253751 the full request and the response are in the question.

Comment: The full request is not in the question.

Comment: @user253751 the full code is in the question, what is missing? If it isn't there I have to add it.

Comment: What request does your program send? Both the one that works, and the one that doesn't.

Comment: The code generates [this](https://pastebin.com/gwSW5a2f) request, which compared to [the documentation](https://api.slack.com/web#posting_json) seems fine. `curl -v` uses HTTP/2 and adds other fields, so direct comparison is not so trivial. It also uses a different content-type than the one specified in the docs.

Sending the request to postman-echo.com it seems the body is never received, but I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: so what happens if you make curl and your program send the same request? Do you get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the POST to `postman-echo.com`, that responds with the request you sent, I could see the body was empty.

Turns out that I was missing one compulsory field in the header, `Content-Length`. When missing, it seems Slack and postman default to 0.
The solution? Add in the header:

```
client.println("Content-Length: 42");
```